# Logarithmic bound on total number of primes less than a particular number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to prove the following inequality
$$
\pi(2 n) \log n-\pi(n) \log \left(\frac{n}{2}+\log 2\right) \leqslant \sum_{k=n \atop k \text { is } \text { pime }}^{2 n} \log k
$$

Here $\pi(n)$ is the number of prime numbers less than or equal to $n$.

I found this inequality while studying a weaker version of Chebyshev's estimate of $\pi(x)$. Using this as a starting point someone proved
$$\pi (2^{k+1})<\frac{6(\log 2) 2^k}{\log(2^k)}.$$

I am not sure how to proceed and I also cannot find any related result on this platform.
It would be helpful if you can provide me some hints or a rough idea on how to prove the above inequality.

Comment: This is the kind of problem where the context would really help. Where did you come across this inequality? Why are you trying to prove this particular statement?

Comment: @GregMartin I found this inequality while studying a weaker version of Chebyshev's estimate of $\pi(x)$. Using this as a starting point someone proved $\pi(2^{k+1})<(6log2)2^{k}/log(2^{k})$

Comment: Using Dusart upper/lower bounds for $\pi,\theta$ functions, the inequality is false for all numbers from some $N_0$ onward, so you need to flip the smaller than to bigger than for the inequality to hold true.

Comment: Well $\log(2n)=\log(n)+\log(2)$ so by PNT there exist a formula ...